# How to draw spherical "caps" onto arbitrary axis using SphericalPlot3D?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I am trying to make a diagram for a project where there intersection of three shapes--two concentric spheres and one cone--is shaded or highlighted or in some way marked out. I currently have the following [image]

But the mesh caps should be rotated pi/2 so that they are centered on the x-axis and not the z-axis. The code I am using to make these caps is

```
cap1 = SphericalPlot3D[6, {\[Theta], Pi/4, 0}, {\[Phi], 0,  2 Pi}, 
  Boxed -> False, PlotPoints -> 50, ImageSize -> Large, 
  Boxed -> False, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0},
  PlotStyle -> {Directive[Gray, Opacity[0.2]], 
    Directive[Gray, Opacity[0.1]]},  
  PlotRange -> {{-12, 12}, {-12, 12}, {-12, 12}}]
```

And ideally I would like to connect them with a strip that lies on the surface of the intersecting cone, but I haven't figured out how to do this yet.

And suggestions would help. I have already had a go with ContourPlot3D and RevolutionPlot3D to no avail.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SphericalPlot3D[]` is not spherically symmetric. The axis $\theta=0$ is special.  But I guess you could rotate your cap:

```
Show[
 Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.4], Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 6]}],
 MapAt[Rotate[#, {{0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0}}] &, cap1, 1]
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

- We can use the implicit form of the cone region `x >= Tan[π/4] Sqrt[y^2 + z^2]]`

```
cap1 = SphericalPlot3D[6, {θ, 0, Pi}, {ϕ, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  Boxed -> False, PlotPoints -> 80, MaxRecursion -> 4, 
  ImageSize -> Large, Boxed -> False, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Directive[Gray, Opacity[0.2]], 
    Directive[Gray, Opacity[0.1]]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-12, 12}, {-12, 12}, {-12, 12}}, 
  RegionFunction -> 
   Function[{x, y, z, θ, φ}, 
    x >= Tan[π/4] Sqrt[y^2 + z^2] || 
     x <= -Tan[π/4] Sqrt[y^2 + z^2] || 
     z >= Tan[π/4] Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]]]
```

[image]

- Or use `ClipPlanes`

```
cap1 = SphericalPlot3D[6, {θ, 0, Pi}, {ϕ, 0, 2 Pi}, 
   Boxed -> False, PlotPoints -> 50, ImageSize -> Large, 
   Boxed -> False, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Directive[Gray, Opacity[0.2]], 
     Directive[Gray, Opacity[0.1]]}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-12, 12}, {-12, 12}, {-12, 12}}];
Graphics3D[cap1[[1]], ClipPlanes -> {{1, 0, 0, -3 Sqrt[2]}}]
```

[image]